# Relaying ISP email through my own email server?

Tags: email, spam-prevention

I'm getting roughly 300 spam emails per month on my ISP email account. Obviously its driving me nuts.

I have a linux server and a windows server at my disposal.

I had an idea to download the email from the ISP direct onto one of these servers as a relay and then have that receiving mail server relay the mail to my email client/phone

In this way, I can set the relay server's spam sensitivity to a point where it will possibly reduce the amount of spam that I'm getting on a daily basis before the emails get to me.

I wanted to find out if this sort of thing is possible. If it is, how can I achieve it?

Comment: I actually laughed and spit out my drink.  I would love 300 a month.  I probably getting 300 spam messages a day.  Thank god for spam filters.

Comment: It doesn't seem like your spam filters are doing you much good if you're getting 300 spam emails a day...

Comment: oh they are going to the spam folder.  i never see them.

Comment: I have all of my spam going there as well... unfortunately my mail client also chucks everything else into the spam folder while its busy

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind using gmail, get a free account and add the ISP mail settings to its list of accounts to poll. This will filter out the spam - Either forward the gmail account to another or use the gmail account.

Comment: So if I understand you correctly, you're saying to let gmail get the mail and then I add gmail to my mail client.

Comment: @Ortund exactly! Personally I've found never to actually use ISP emails as you never know when they might decide to get rid of them/close them down/or you might change ISP. This would allow you to migrate to gmail easily if you wanted to as well.

Comment: Well, the damn thing keeps asking me for my password to log in to imap.googlemail.com and I know I've typed the credentials correctly... So this isn't going very well

Comment: Don't forget to actually [allow password authentication](https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps) for IMAP.

Comment: What email client are you using? There are specific instructions for each client online - They use different port settings to most other email providers, and autodetect settings doesn't work in most cases.